# Microservice - Video file attachment

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I am working on building a microservice using Spring Boot. There is a requirement to return large video file attachment. Is it possible to return video attachments as part of REST response? Since the files are huge I am bit skeptical on how these services scale. Is it common to attach large video files as part of REST response or are there any alternate approaches available?

Comment: you can stream video using **StreamingResponseBody**, the best approach will be to delegate streaming to some other container likbe nginix and only return video URL from your Spring boot APP, with this approach your Spring Boot APP will be free from video streaming and can serve other request.

Comment: Removed the tag "drools" - not even remotely connected with the Q.

Comment: Thanks @Apollo and @laune!